# Howto know when appcache is done?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Is there a way to know when a webview has done caching the files requested by a HTML5 manifest ?

Here is what I'm doing but I could end up with incomplete display when offline (missing some images)

```
//v is my WebView instance
String cachePath = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/cache";
v.getSettings().setAppCachePath(cachePath);
v.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*4); // 4Mo default cache size
v.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
v.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
v.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfos = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(null != netInfos && netInfos.isConnected()) {
    v.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}
else {
    File f = new File(cachePath);
    if(f.exists()){
        v.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
    }
    else{
        url = fallbackUrl;
    }
}
```

I would like to be notified when the cache is done or even better to know if the cache directory is "corrupted" or not.

Comment: Do you have access to the [`cached` and `updateready` events](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#event-appcache-cached)?

Comment: Do you mean on the Js side? If so then yes. I'll check that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The original poster put this as an update to the question, but it's really an answer, so I'm moving it here:

**All remaining content from original poster**:

Thanks to robertc suggestion, here is what I'm doing now:

On the JS side I'm listening for the cached event.
When it's fired, I call a method on my JS interface that create a file "cachepresent.dummy" in the android cache folder. This way I could know if the cache is complete or not on the android side by testing if this file exists.
Using the same mechanism I'm clearing the whole android cache folder when the updateready event is triggered.

Here is the java code:

```
private class JsInterface {

    public JsInterface() {}

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void cached() {
        File f = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/cache/cachepresent.dummy");
        FileWriter w;
        try {
            w = new FileWriter(f);
            w.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void DeleteRecursive(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : f.listFiles()) {
                DeleteRecursive(child);
            }
        }
        f.delete();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void clearCache(){
        File f = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/cache");
        DeleteRecursive(f);
    }

}
...
//add the javascript interface to the webview
jsInterface = new JsInterface();
v.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JsBridge");

//Check if the cache is complete
File cachePresentFile = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/cache/cachepresent.dummy");
boolean cachePresent = cachePresentFile.exists();
```

And the JS code:

```
    function cacheReload() {
        var cache = window.applicationCache;
        try{
            cache.update();
        }
        catch(e){
            //android 2.2 does not seem to support this :'(
            console.log("JS Exception: " + e);
        }
        cache.addEventListener("updateready",
            function () {
                JsBridge.clearCache();
                cache.swapCache();
                window.location.reload();
            }
        );

        cache.addEventListener("cached",
            function () {
                JsBridge.cached();
            }
        );
    }
```

BTW I'm pretty sure there is a smarter way to achieve this by using the HTML5 LocalStorage stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Troot, I'll try to remember to create a new post next time :)